# How fast is the HTTPWebRequest class?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I was wondering, how fast the HTTPWebRequest is in comparision with a self-written parser for the HTTP-Response.

I know the HTTPWebRequest class is capable of using a persistent TCP connection with pipelining (pipelining is enabled by default). It's also possible to set values for caching and compression.

The parsing of the response is probably never the bottleneck, but just for my curiosity: Does the HTTPWebRequest class produce "unnecessary" overhead?

Comment: I can't think what you could consider a correct answer.  It has features, they may or may not align with what you need.  It has performance, that may or may not align with what you need.  You want someone to profile for you?

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone: No I don't want someone to profile for me. I'm trying to encourage someone who has already done profiling in the past to share his results. If nobody answers I can easily delete the question in the future. Thanks for the downvote anyway

Comment: For clarification: I have not written a parser myself, I was just curious if there are known speed problems with the HTTPWebRequest class

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: IMNSHO the speed problems will come from your bandwidth/latency, unless the program is running on a toaster. Note that writing your own, usable parser for HTTP requests is a much trickier business than it seems at first glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what the self-written parser is, it's not possible to give a quantified answer to your question. That said, you **might** be able to write a parser that *is* quicker than `HTTPWebRequest`, if (for example):

- Your response will only ever contain a certain set of headers
- The headers will only ever be returned in a certain order
- Your request will only ever go to one destination
- Any other constraints you can use to limit the processing that will be performed on the response

If you can constrain the scenario, you may be able to outperform `HTTPWebRequest` as it has to be able to handle *any* **valid** response, whereas a custom parser has to only be able to handle scenarios it's expecting. That said, bear in mind that what you're writing won't then be a **true** HTTP response parser, rather something that handles a strict sub-set of valid responses.

The only way you can tell if there's any overhead which you can avoid is by writing your own (sub-set) parser and comparing its performance to that of the in-built one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a conclusion, but I believe this kind of questions should be motivated by an actual case scenario. For example, does HttpWebRequest class slowdowns your solution? Have you checked its performance impact using some profiler?

And, after all, there's a well-known sentence about this kind of questions regarding optimization: *premature optimization is the devil of any software development*.

My best suggestion is you should take care about other things, use a good profiler and find out where your program have performance issues (I'm sure HttpWebRequest won't be the problem!).